# Taskeng.exe multiple process

Tags: batch-file, scripting, task, scheduler

I've created two Batch scripts that I launch via the windows 7's Task Scheduler, and I've noticed that from times to times the execution of one of these scripts freezes. When this happens I get a Taskeng.exe window, and the only way to get rid of it is to kill the equivalent process.

And since I'm running those scripts on differents machines, whenever I log on in the morning, I find multiple Taskeng.exe windows from the previous executions.

Is there anyway to solve this problem ? Is there a way to kill those processes whenever their execution is incomplete ?

Thanks for reading.
Hicham

Comment: What happens if you set the scheduler option to kill a task if it takes longer than a defined time?

Comment: I already activated the option to end the task if it freezes, and if a task is still running at the time of the next execution it ends the first one.